# SQL SERVER 2000 JDBC DRIVER

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2000

I am trying to find the SQL SERVER 2000 JDBC Driver to use in extracting data from SQL SERVER and also carrying out several operation implemented in Java/JSF. Any idea where I could get my hands on the driver? It is no surprise that Microsoft.com /MSDN stopped supporting and hence supplying the necessary driver. Please help and it is greatly appreciated

P.S. Sorry if this is the wrong place to post this :)

EDIT: Solution Working:

So JTDS does it based on link below. The strings I changed to make it work for SQL SERVER 2000 are:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

and

```
connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host;", "username",
                   "password");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1511

Or
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/

Comment: This is the same msdn link I went to...if you take a closer look, you will find that the size is 1KB and thats readme. they no longer supply it for download.

Comment: it did work! Thanks mate! I am editing original post to include working code :)

Comment: The MS page contains the link to the d/l for the driver, you just have to click through a little more. Sorry, I should have deep-linked a little further.

Comment: sorry too for not going further enough myself :)