# Connecting to a SQL Server 2000 db from Java

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2000

I am receiving an error that I did see on your site, but as a novice java coder I think that I flubbed my implementation of the solution.

I am getting a message 
"SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. ClientConnectionId:602d619d-c033-41d0-9109-80f56e3ab9b3"

I am using Eclipse Mars 1
The database is a sql server 2000, so I downloaded sqljdbc.jar from the Microsoft site as suggested by an earlier question.  I loaded it to c:\temp and added that to the CLASSPATH and rebooted.

code snippet reads:

```
package texasLAMPConversion;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TexasLAMPConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String host = "jdbc:sqlserver://serverName\\instanceName";
        String uName = "*********";
        String uPass = "*********";
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
             conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName,uPass);
             if (conn != null) {                                System.out.println("Connected to the database");
              } 
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        FileWriter fw= null;
        File file =null;
           try {
                file=new File("C:/temp/generated_stmts_update_t_customer_master.sql");
                if(!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                fw = new FileWriter(file);
           }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

        String  oldKey = "8000001234", newKey = "8";
        int     lenAcct = 10;
        oldKey = ReformatOldAcct(lenAcct, oldKey );
        newKey = leftZeroAcct(lenAcct, newKey);
        System.out.println("oldkey = " + oldKey + " and newKey = " + newKey);

    }

    private static String ReformatOldAcct(int lenAcct, String oldKey) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String reformatedAcct = "";
        reformatedAcct = "0" + oldKey.substring(2, lenAcct);
        return (reformatedAcct);

    }

    private static String leftZeroAcct(int lenAcct, String acctNo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int index =0;
        int currentLengthAcct;
        String  leadingZero = "";
        currentLengthAcct = acctNo.length();

        while (index < (lenAcct -currentLengthAcct) ) {
            leadingZero = '0'  + leadingZero;
            index ++;
        }
        return (leadingZero + acctNo);
    }

}
```

and it is throwing this complete message

Apr 19, 2016 11:29:44 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
WARNING: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 602d619d-c033-41d0-9109-80f56e3ab9b3 Server major version:8 is not supported by this driver.
Apr 19, 2016 11:29:44 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
WARNING: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 602d619d-c033-41d0-9109-80f56e3ab9b3 Server major version:8 is not supported by this driver.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. ClientConnectionId:602d619d-c033-41d0-9109-80f56e3ab9b3com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. ClientConnectionId:602d619d-c033-41d0-9109-80f56e3ab9b3

```
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2226)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2226)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2210)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2210)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:2095)

at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:2095)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1799)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1799)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1454)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1454)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1285)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1285)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1131)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1131)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at texasLAMPConversion.TexasLAMPConversion.main(TexasLAMPConversion.java:20)
at texasLAMPConversion.TexasLAMPConversion.main(TexasLAMPConversion.java:20)
```

SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. ClientConnectionId:602d619d-c033-41d0-9109-80f56e3ab9b3
SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. ClientConnectionId:602d619d-c033-41d0-9109-80f56e3ab9b3

Any thoughts for a novice java programmer moving away from PowerBuilder?

Comment: Did you download the Microsoft JDBC driver recommended in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9747998/2144390)?

Comment: Things are actually slightly better.  I had forgotten that I had to add the jar for sql on the library tab.  I changed the reference to the current jar file name and my error message is now shorter
"No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://JDCDBETST005\TSYSTEM01
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://JDCDBETST005\TSYSTEM01
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at texasLAMPConversion.TexasLAMPConversion.main(TexasLAMPConversion.java:20)

Comment: Not so much "better" as "different". Previously you were getting a message saying "I found a driver but it is incompatible", whereas now you're getting a message saying "I can't find a (suitable) driver at all".

Comment: I downloaded Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21599

The system requirements included sql 2000 so I thought it was ok.  I will try the other one that you noted.

Comment: Thanks, Gord Thompson--
After much agonizing, this did solve my connection problem.  I downloaded the jtds driver. I finally realized that the jar file had to be added to the build path screen (novice, remember).  Then, suffered through how to actually formatting the URL format.  My reward is the message "connected to the database"  Wow!